# Create an Android ActionBar with Tabs via XML file only

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar-compat

I'm a newbie in Android development. I'm following the tutorial on this page, and trying to get an actionbar with tabs. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

My code seems to be exactly same as the sample in the page, except for the "android:drawable" in actionbar_tab_indicator.xml. 
I used @color/blablabla rather than the @drawable/blablabla in the sample in that web page. But based on my knowledge, @color and @drawable are replaceable of each other. 
Yet, I'm not getting any tab when I run the application. Only an activity with an actionbar. And the whole background is black(blank?).

Here is my themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->

    <style name="TabTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabs</item>
        <!--  android support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabs</item>
    </style>

        <!-- ActionBar tabs styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTabs"
           parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
        <!-- tab indicator -->
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator</item>
        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And here is my actionbar_tab_indicator.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- STATES WHEN BUTTON IS NOT PRESSED -->

    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@color/gold" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@color/articlecolor" />

    <!-- Focused states (such as when focused with a d-pad or mouse hover) -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@color/gold" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@color/articlecolor" />


<!-- STATES WHEN BUTTON IS PRESSED -->

    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@color/black" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/blue" />

    <!-- Focused states (such as when focused with a d-pad or mouse hover) -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@color/black" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@color/blue" />
</selector >
```

I'm so confused; any help is appreciated. I'm using support compat library by the way

Comment: Heads up, tabs in the actionbar are deprecated in Android L. You may want to rethink your navigation before then. http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/06/28/and-now-your-l-api-change-wtfs.html

Comment: @Krylez Thank you for the info. But also do u see anything wrong with my xml code?

Answer (score 0):

use `android:background="@drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator"` to set the background color of the xml.

Also to use your theme, make sure you set `android:theme="@style/TabTheme"`

Comment: I think I did it in the last 5th line of my themes.xml